Why primefaces ajax rowSelect event oncomplete method argument id is empty?
My code:
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable var="article" value="#{articleTable.articles}" lazy="true"
                 selection="#{articleTable.selected}" selectionMode="single"
                 emptyMessage="#{text['emptyMessage']}" rowKey="#{article.id}">
        <p:column style="display:none;">
            <h:outputText value="#{article.id}" />
        </p:column>
        
        <p:column headerText="#{text['titleText']}">
            <h:outputText value="#{article.title}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="#{text['summaryText']}">
            <h:outputText value="#{article.summary}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="#{text['categoryText']}">
            <h:outputText value="#{article.category}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="#{text['statusText']}">
            <h:outputText value="#{article.status.text}" />
        </p:column>
        
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                oncomplete="handleRowSelect('#{article.id}')"/>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleRowSelect(id) {
            if ( id )
                window.location.href = 'article.xhtml?id=' + id;
        }
    </script>

#{article.id} has value, but "handleRowSelect('#{article.id}')" argument value is '' empty.
I use Chrome F12; it has called handleRowSelect() method, but the id value is '' empty; why?
Why the argument is empty?
And how do I fix it?
Do I have to use commandLink or commandButton? Can't I click on a row to redirect page?

No one answer me...
I found 2 way solution:


<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{articleTable.navigateToDetail}"/> But it turn back to redirect.


<p:dataTable id="articleTable" widgetVar="articleTable"> and var id = PF('articleTable').selection;.


Why not each row call redirect method with id itself?

Can you share the lazyload function?

I answered your question here on why you are using the component incorrectly: https://github.com/orgs/primefaces/discussions/2765

@ÖmerFarukKurt I didn't implement the lazy relate function, but I remain lazy property; excuse me.
You can visit the link '2765' above refer for executable example, thanks. :)
